# draw text using coregraphics in iphone

Tags: iphone, text, core-graphics

How to draw text on imageview using coregraphics in iphone

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Either use a UILabel over your imageView or draw a string in the current graphics context with

```
- (CGSize)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect withFont:(UIFont *)font lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
```

Comment: Just to expand on the answer, this is a method on NSString.  So, for example:

`[@"test" drawInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:8]];`

Comment: This text gets up-side down when I use it with coregraphics image drawing code where I have to CGContextScaleCTM and CGContextTranslateCTM to convert between coregraphics and device coordinates system. How can I not have these lines effect on string drawrect method?

Answer (score 0):

TextImageView.h

```
@interface TextImageView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *text;

@end
```

TextImageView.m

```
@implementation TextImageView

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [self.image drawInRect:self.bounds];
    [self.text drawInRect:self.bounds
           withAttributes:@{}];
}

@end
```

The method in the accepted answer has been deprecated. The method that you would want to use instead is [`- [NSString drawInRect:withAttributes:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawInRect:withAttributes:).

You are supposed to call this method from within the `drawRect:` method of a `UIView` subclass, but if you subclass `UIImageView`, `drawRect:` will never be called. ([From the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/): "UIImageView does not call the drawRect: method of its subclasses.")

So, you really can't draw text on a `UIImageView`, but you can subclass `UIView` and have it draw an image with text on top as proposed above.